# disable checkbox after checking two vuejs

Tags: vue.js

how can I disable an array of checkbox after checking a number of checkboxes from that array ? 
Is there a way to do this in vuejs or I will need a watcher for that?
In fact I tried to watch the 'ord.sauce' but I couldnt make it work

**this is the component**

```
Vue.component('sauce-view', {
props: ["sauce", "ord", "name"],
template: '
    <div class="">
            <input type="checkbox" :name="name" :value="sauce.id" v-model="ord.sauce">  
            {{sauce.name}}
        <label >
            <img :src="sauce.link" >
        </label>
    </div>',
  });
```

**This is the HTML**

```
<table>
<tr v-for="o in order" >
       {{o.sauce}}      
     <td v-for="sauce in les_sauces" >
        <sauce-view :sauce="sauce" :ord="o" :name="o.produit+o.num">
        </sauce-view>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have created a simple fiddle that should illustrate the logic behind it: https://jsfiddle.net/UDany/r9q4x85d/

This would be the markup:

```
<div id="demo">
  <template v-for="(item, index) in itemlist">
    <label><input type="checkbox" :value="index" name="condiment" v-model="selectedItems" :disabled="selectedItems.length >= max && selectedItems.indexOf(index) == -1" /> {{item}}</label>
  </template>
  <div>{{selectedItems.join(', ')}}</div>
</div>
```

And your JS would look like this:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        selectedItems: [],
        itemlist: [
                "Mayo",
                "Ketchup",
                "Mustard",
                "Honey"
        ],
        max: 2
    }
})
```

Since you're not using the input directly into the main code you'll need to proxy the properties through/from it (possibly wiring events for "select" and "unselect" and having a property for "disabled")

Comment: why do we need this "selectedItems.indexOf(index) == -1" in the condition?

Comment: @brahimm this makes sure it doesn't disable the currently checked checkboxes. In an array indexOf returns the index of the value it receives OR -1 if it wasn't able to find it, thus "selectedItems.indexOf(index) == -1" will only return true if the value can't be found within the selectedItems array.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a question very similar to this here:

[Vue.js limit selected checkboxes to 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142744/vue-js-limit-selected-checkboxes-to-5/35143949#35143949)

In your situation it's a little more involved since you're handling the value in a component. It's hard to tell your exact needs so I'd clear up your question a little more.

Comment: the idea is clever, I didnt think of it first time, but it disables all the inputs, and I need the checked-boxes to stay able to be unchecked to that I can control that the user check only two (for example)

Comment: The code in that answer doesn't disable checked inputs so you'll always be able to unselect them.