# Vue allow only one element in array be true

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating multiple input fields with checkboxes in vue and I want that only one can be true. So if the user clicks on one the others should be false so that only the last clicked checkbox is true.

My code is like that:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      selected: null,
      options: [
          {"id": 1, "title": "One", "value": false},
          {"id": 2, "title": "Two", "value": false },
          {"id": 3, "title": "Three", "value": false},
      ]
  },
  watch: {
    selected(selected) {
      this.options.forEach((option, index) => {
        option.id == selected ? option.value = true : option.value = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately my watcher isn't working properly. I would be really glad if somebody can show me how to correct it. I want that always the last true element is the only true element and the watches sets all other elements in options to false.

Comment: Just a question: Does it have to be a checkbox? Radio buttons are usually better suited for those requirements.

Comment: make it a computed -> `({id, title, value: id === this.selected})`

Comment: @puelo Later I'll use `</b-switch>` element from buefy this is a switch so this is my problem I **MUST** make the decision in javascript. I've used checkbox here just to showcase the scenario.

Comment: Looks like this should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142744/vue-js-limit-selected-checkboxes-to-5

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify my desired solutions isn't DOM related

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your requirements correctly you can still do it with radio buttons. You can specify the value to be used inside the `selected` variable, as described here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio-1. This means that you can set up a watcher and then mutate the options list accordingly:

```
selected: function (newVal) {
    this.options.forEach(option => {
      if (option.id === newVal) option.value = true
      else option.value = false
    })
    console.log(this.options)
}
```

Here is a sandbox to see it in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-goldberg-lilsw

Update: Just saw that you want to use the `</b-switch>` from buefy. You can still do something similar by calling a function from the `input` event which then mutates the options list according to the just changed element. Something like this:

```
<div v-for="(option,index) in options" :key="index">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="field">
           <b-switch v-model="option.value" @input="(modelValue) => onSwitchChanged(modelValue, option.id)">
            {{ option.title }}
           </b-switch>
          <label :for="index">{{ option.title }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function onSwitchChanged(modelValue, id) {
    if (!modelValue) return
    this.options.forEach(option => {
      if (option.id === id) option.value = true
      else option.value = false
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much I tried your solution now in JSfiddle and it seems to work good I'll try that tomorrow with `</b-switch>` element in my project but I see no reason why this shouldn't work cause `onSwitchChanged` was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

If you want that **Only One** will be selected then you have to use `radio` button. `Checkbox` has options to select all **But One by One**.

Without `watch` you can use `methods`. Pass index to the method.

```
<input 
   type="checkbox"
   :id="index" 
   :value="option.id" 
   @click="selectAnOption(index)"
>
```

Method:

```
methods: {
  selectAnOption(index) {
   this.options[index].value = true
  }
}
```

Full Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/8ktdp9ew/

Comment: But my problem is I will use later `</b-switch>` which is an switch from buefy framework so i **MUST** make the decision in JavaScript ( set all others to false when one is true ).

Comment: Then why you are not using `radio`? Why Checkbox?

Comment: As I said only repeat it I **can't** use radio buttons! so I **MUST** make the decision in javascript.